# error when use "rake db:migrate" on Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake-task, dbmigrate

I'm use "rake db:migrate" and getting this error message:
Pls help me to fix that:

```
# rake db:migrate rake aborted! 
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
Directly inheriting from ActiveRecord::Migration is not supported. Please specify the Rails release the migration was written for:
  class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2] 
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:528:in `inherited' 
/root/genieacs-gui/db/migrate/20160202145722_create_users.rb:1:in `<top (required)>' 
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require' 
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require' 
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency' 
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require' 
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:986:in `load_migration' 
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:982:in `migration' 
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:977:in `disable_ddl_transaction' 
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1350:in `use_transaction?' 
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1342:in `ddl_transaction' 
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1291:in `execute_migration_in_transaction' 
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1263:in `block in migrate_without_lock' 
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1262:in `each' 
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1262:in `migrate_without_lock' 
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1212:in `migrate' 
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1036:in `up' 
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1011:in `migrate' 
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:172:in `migrate' 
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:60:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>' 
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
#...
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Comment: The first line of the error explains what to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your migrations in `db/migrate` directory should all inherit from `ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]`, not `ActiveRecord::Migration`

Comment: Hi kevcha,
Can I edit by command below ?
grep -rl "ActiveRecord::Migration$" db | xargs sed -i 's/ActiveRecord::Migration/ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]/g'